# Understanding why there is an Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I have some code and I try to figure out, why I'm getting an segmentation fault here:

I add a `SpeedEffect` to a `EffectStack`, this works quite well. But if I try to remove one of the `Effects` (which are already on the stack) I have to call `effect.removeEffect()`. This causes a segmentation fault.

If I try to call `effect.removeEffect()` from the `TestStack()` function, it works well (and prints the expected "speed effect removed" on the console)

```
void Test::testStack() {
    Story* st = new Story; //<-- only needed for initialization of an Effect
    Veins::TraCIMobility* mob = new Veins::TraCIMobility; //<-- only needed for initialization of an Effect
    SpeedEffect a = SpeedEffect(1.0, st, mob);

    a.removeEffect();  //<-- This one works quite well
    (&a)->removeEffect();  //<-- Clearly, this works too

    EffectStack s;
    s.addEffect(&a);  //<-- Adds a Effect to the effect Stack
    assert(s.getEffects().size() == 1);

    s.removeEffect(&a); //<-- Try to remove effect from stack
}
```

The `Stack` and the `Effect` are implemented as following:

```
class Effect {
public:
    Effect(Story* story, Veins::TraCIMobility* car) :
        m_story(story), m_car(car) {}

    virtual void removeEffect() = 0;
private:
    Story* m_story;
protected:
    Veins::TraCIMobility* m_car;
};


class SpeedEffect : public Effect {
public:
    SpeedEffect(double speed, Story* story, Veins::TraCIMobility* car):
        Effect(story, car), m_speed(speed){}

    void removeEffect() {
        std::cout << "speed effect removed" << std::endl;
    }

private:
    double m_speed;
};


class EffectStack {
public:
    void addEffect(Effect* effect) {
        if(std::count(m_effects.begin(), m_effects.end(), effect) == 0) {
            m_effects.push_back(effect);
        }
    }

    void removeEffect(Effect* effect) {
        if(effect == m_effects.back()) {
            //effect is pointing on the same address like its doing before, but causes the seg fault
            m_effects.back()->removeEffect(); //<--- Seg Fault here!!
            effect->removeEffect(); //<-- if I use this, seg fault too
            m_effects.pop_back();
        }else {
            removeFromMiddle(effect);
        }
    }

    const std::vector<Effect*>& getEffects() {
        return m_effects;
    }

private:
    std::vector<Effect*> m_effects;
};
```

I hope this code is enough, I have removed all functions which are not called by the testing scenario.

Is there any problem, because the address of the `speedEffect` a becomes invalid in the `Stack`?

Maybe you can help me with this.

---

New thoughts about the question:
No I have tested a bit more, which makes me even more confused:

```
void dofoo(SpeedEffect* ef) {
    ef->removeEffect(); //<-- breaks with a segmentation fault
}

void Test::testStack() {
    Story* st = new Story;
    Veins::TraCIMobility* mob = new Veins::TraCIMobility;
    SpeedEffect e = SpeedEffect(3.0, st, mob);

    e.removeEffect(); //<-- Works fine
    (&e)->removeEffect(); //<-- Works fine also
    dofoo(&a); //<-- Jumps into the dofoo() function
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but it doesn't seem like `EffectStack` should really be a stack; it seems like you're using it more like a set.

Comment: s.removeEffect(&a); //..if this works, then where does it fail??

Comment: also, m_effects.back()...back() on an empty vector is undefined behaviour??check for size() before you call back()

Comment: `s.removeEffect(&a); //<-- Try to remove effect from stack` fails, because the call `effect->removeEffect(); //<-- if I use this, seg fault too` fails. If I use the GDB, I can not step into the `effect->removeEffect();` method, if its called inside the Effect Stack

Comment: You are right, I have to check if the vector is empty. But this is not not the problem here.. I do not understand, why I can call the `effect.removeEffect` method before adding it to the Stack object but not inside the Stack object ( unimportant if I use the pointer, located in the vector, or the pointer which is passed directly to the removeEffect function of the EffectStack)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not help you, but persisting the address of stack-based objects is usually not a great idea. In your code above it's potentially okay since you know EffectStack won't outlive your effect.

Does the crash still occur if you do:

```
SpeedEffect* a = new SpeedEffect(1.0, st, mob);
```

(and adjust the rest of the code accordingly?) This will leak memory of course, but it will tell you if the problem is SpeedEffect being destroyed. Another option is to give SpeedEffect a destructor (and Effect a virtual destructor) and set a breakpoint inside to see when the the compiler is destroying 'a'.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be an answer.  In the posted code `a` lasts long enough that the stack-based issue should not be the problem.

Comment: Yes.. I think the main question is, why can I call the `removeEffect` on an effect object in the Testing scenario but not if I have passed the Object to the Stack.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Story* st = new Story; //<-- only needed for initialization of an Effect
    Veins::TraCIMobility* mob = new Veins::TraCIMobility; //<-- only needed for initialization
```

I don't see the `delete st` and `delete mob` - there is memory allocated for these objects inside void `Test::testStack()` but not explicitly released.
add these two statement at the end of the function and try again.

Comment: Yea, thats right, I do not delete them, because there is no deletion of any object in the code. I only try to remove the address from my "stack". I have to have this statements at the beginning, because I can not create an Effect object, without a Story and without a Mobility 0bject

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem.
I'm using the omnet Simulation framework and there is something unexpected happening if I instanciate the TraciMobility.. 
So without it, there is no error..